# Mongoose Promise error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, mongoose-schema

This is the error which is still being thrown when saving even after adding native promise.

> (node:5604) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/optimusCP')
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Connected to MONGOD !!');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Failed to establish connection with MONGOD !!');
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

I have tried both bluebird & q, still haven't found a fix for this.
Below is the code when I save this, the following deprecation warning shows up..

```
var user = new User();
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = hash;
        user.save()
            .then(function (user) {
                console.log(user);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

> This error is happening on the new version of mongoose which is 4.8.1, but working fine on 4.7.6 mongoose version.

Comment: have you read the last section about **Promises for the MongoDB Driver**

Comment: From docs ? If so yes..

Comment: it's just that you haven't shown that part of your code

Comment: I have updated with my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite using `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` before `mongoose.connect(...)`, I had the same warning.

I discovered, that I initialized mongoose connection in one file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

...

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, mongoOptions);
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

But I imported `mongoose` in another file too (where mongoose scheme was described), so I added `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` in second file too, as a result of it, the warning disappeared.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const UserSchema = new Schema({ ... });
```

May be you have the same case.

Comment: Bro you saved my life (just kidding) Right answer bro (y)

Comment: I have same problem but did like your snippet but not work . Can you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success getting rid of the message with this

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used bluebird for using promise with mongoose model functions node v6.9.4 :

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that I have tried using both bluebird and q, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Mongoose from 4.8.1 to 4.9.1 solved my problem.