# Does mongoose promise error result in high CPU usage for queries?

Tags: mongoose, promise, cpu-usage

I am posting it as a separate question as I am new here and hence I'm unable to comment.

The answer I viewed here says the Mongoose promise error can be fixed by adding the following line before mongoose.connect and before declaring any schema (if mongoose is referenced there as well):

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

However, I have the following query:

I need to know how critical is it. I am getting repeated high CPU usage alerts on my node azure app. However, they are random in nature. Right now, my code has no exceptions but this promise warning is thrown everytime.

I have "required" the "mongoose" library in all my schema files, so I would need to add the line in all those files.

Can anyone of you tell me with proper facts if the high CPU usage is related to this?

Further, is it just a avoidable warning or I need to get rid of it?
I am thinking over it as in the latter case, I would have to modify multiple files on production App.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a  link to the original question this is a follow-up to?

Comment: Hi @JohnnyHK, following is the link to the original question which has the correct answer given:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936968/mongoose-promise-error

However, i need to confirm if thats causing me high CPU usage, before i implement the same. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that has anything to do with the CPU issue, but to test it, you'd only have to make the `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` change in _one_ of your files as modules are cached and shared between files. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097375/mongoose-node-js-module-causes-high-cpu-usage

Comment: Alright got it. I will update and check. I believe my node process is getting crashed due to some reason. I had put logs and i can see that even if my queries take a lot of time, they do get executed successfully. So, can you think of anything else which is causing this high CPU usage? I will try with lean command though.